# Error setting up EGit in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, egit, eclipse-juno

I'm trying to install EGit into Eclipse Juno. But, I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Command Line Interface for Java implementation of Git 4.4.0.201606070830-r (org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.feature.group 4.4.0.201606070830-r)
Missing requirement: JGit Large File Storage Server 4.4.0.201606070830-r (org.eclipse.jgit.lfs.server 4.4.0.201606070830-r) requires 'package javax.servlet [3.1.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Java implementation of Git - optional LFS support 4.4.0.201606070830-r (org.eclipse.jgit.lfs.feature.group 4.4.0.201606070830-r)
To: org.eclipse.jgit.lfs.server [4.4.0.201606070830-r]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Command Line Interface for Java implementation of Git 4.4.0.201606070830-r (org.eclipse.jgit.pgm.feature.group 4.4.0.201606070830-r)
To: org.eclipse.jgit.lfs.feature.group [4.4.0.201606070830-r]
```

I've tried removing a few components after I add the repository but don't seem to find a way around it. Can anyone suggest what I can do? I tried googling for the missing dependency `package javax.servlet [3.1.0,4.0.0)`

Answer (score 2):

Your version of Eclipse is too old to install this code.

The message 'requires 'package javax.servlet [3.1.0,4.0.0)'' is saying the minimum version of the 'javax.servlet' plugin required is 3.1.0. Eclipse Juno has 3.0.0